# AngularJS 1.4.8 - how to show ng-repeat text only the first time

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of category, subcategory and product to display and i would like to show the category and subcategory only the first time it is repeated.
Like

```
category      subcategory       product
fruit         apple             McIntosh
fruit         apple             Cortland
cookies       chocolate         Cocolatos
```

I would like to display a list like

```
fruit - apple
       McIntosh
       Cortland
cookies - chocolate
       Cocolatos
```

I used ng-repeat and bootstrap class="row" but I can't get to display the category only the fist time around

Thanks

Comment: One approach is to use the groupBy filter of the [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) module. Another is to pre process your data in such a way that you can use nested ng-repeat

Comment: I finally decided to change my back end structure to be ng-repeat friendly, it also reduced the response size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [`groupBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) function (the underscore library has this out of the box, I bet lodash has it too) on the 'catagory' property, then you need to use nested `ng-repeat`s to display your data, the first one to iterate over the newly created groups, and the inner one to iterate the products.

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6G2JAxIMlAVKwYerFN3z?p=preview) that does just that!